# How does Angular update the view after a $digest cycle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

Does it:

1) Run through the DOM (starting at `ng-app`) and if it sees a DOM node with a directive, update that DOM node with the corresponding model value.

or

2) In running through the `$$watchers` list, if it detects a change, it has a reference to the DOM node it needs to update, so it just does that (so rather than running through the whole DOM, using this approach, it'd store and use a reference to a node in `$$watchers`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more of the second approach.

Angular does all it's heavy lifting via directives. Pretty much everything you use in Angular is a directive:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller>
<button ng-click>

<!-- input is actually a directive -->
<input ng-model="foo" />
```

All those little directives get a reference to the DOM element they are attached to, as well as a `$scope` object. **The directives simply register a callback to be executed when something changes.**

As you have already noted, these are called **watchers.**

Scope is heirarchical, so there is always a tree of related objects that make up your application state. When a `$digest` loop kicks off, it recursively walks that tree looking for changes, and firing off the callbacks *(aka watchers)*.

**The callback can then choose to do whatever the heck it wants. It's just that in most cases, it's updating the DOM.**

At the end of the day there really is nothing magical about how it happens. Just a structure of callbacks, that get executed when something changes.

Here is a silly example of a custom directive that registers a watcher and updates the DOM whenever some property changes.

```js
(function(){

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
  
  function updateValue(){
    return {
      restrict:'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        elem.on('click', function(){
          //You would never actually do this, but
          // it's a demo
          scope[attrs.updateValue] = "rgb(" + 
            getRandomInt(0, 255) + "," +
            getRandomInt(0, 255) + "," +
            getRandomInt(0, 255) + ")";
          
          //kick off a digest loop manually
          // this is similar to what a lot of angular
          // directives do.
          scope.$digest();
        });
      }
    };
  }
  
  function sillyDomChangeOn(){
    return {
      restrict:'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.sillyDomChangeOn, function(newVal, oldVal){
          elem.css('color', newVal);
        });
      }
    };
  }
  
  angular.module('my-app', [])
    .directive('updateValue', updateValue)
    .directive('sillyDomChangeOn', sillyDomChangeOn);

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<div ng-app="my-app" class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" update-value="randomVal">Update Value</button>
  <h3>Value: <code>{{randomVal}}</code></h3>
  <div class="well" silly-dom-change-on="randomVal">
  <h3>This is just a random DIV</h3>
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that you explained it it makes sense, but I initially forgot about how the digest cycle relates to directives. I now understand that it's (often) called inside a directive where it has access to the DOM element (_that's_ how it accesses the DOM element!). Relevant link to [ngBind's source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L63).